# How to draw jpeg images using Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, java-2d

I have to make a Java program that gets XML files with simple snippets of code from several programming languages and draws them into a flowchart and makes it into a JPEG/PNG image, now I know it must be possible to do this but so far I haven't found anything to help me figure out how I can make Java draw an image and make it into a JPEG.

Is there any library I can use? A tutorial on this? Anything?

Comment: Searching for ["java write image"](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+write+image) and ["java draw image"](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+draw+image) both yield https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/ in the first two search results.

Comment: imagemagick is pretty impressive though I last used it about 10 years ago. Are you sure that generating SVG isn't more appropriate nowadays? It should be much easier. And for things like flowcharts, consider GraphViz.